# Java - How to run init method in Main class

Tags: java

I'm want to run my gui, but I don't really know how to initialize this class. I'm transitioning from python to Java, so I'm still fairly new to this. The code works, I just need to know how to run it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

// Where the main run function for the application will lie
public class MainWindow extends JFrame{
    public void init(){

        // Initial window
        JFrame startFrame = new JFrame("P.D");
        startFrame.setSize(1200, 800);
        startFrame.setVisible(true);
        startFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Panel to hold our buttons
        JPanel startPanel = new JPanel();
        startFrame.add(startPanel);


        // Button to initialize everything
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startPanel.add(startButton);
        startFrame.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        startFrame.add(startButton, new GridBagConstraints());


        // Take out the border around the text
        startButton.setFocusable(false);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    }
}
```

**How do I run the init() method under static void main(String[] args?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose you just create a new MainWindow object in main method and call the `init()` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        new MainWindow().init();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the function by making it static.
Like python "static method".

```
public static void init(){
```

..
And:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      init();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement constructor instead of init() method and you can start gui like below

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```